# Visual Basic 6 - Convert scientific notation to double

Tags: text, vb6, numbers, double

Very simple.

I want to be able to convert scientific notation to a double in Visual Basic 6.

For example :

```
5.97427068015303E-10
```

I have tried :

```
results.Text = CDbl("5.97427068015303E-10")
results.Text = CDbl(5.97427068015303E-10)
```

Not working...

Comment: Not working means: [ ] you have an error. [ ] you get the wrong value. [ ] your computer explodes ?

Answer (score 2):

The value `5.97427068015303E-10` *already is* a Double value.  I don't think the word convert means what you think it does.  Conversion functions certainly won't accomplish what you appear to be after.

I suspect what you are trying to express is that you want to *format* such tiny values as text in simple decimal notation.  If so you might try something like:

```
Text1.Text = Format$(5.97427068015303E-10, "0.0########################")
```